# Is the bold part of the following sentence problematic?

Tags: grammar, dangling-participles, dangling-modifiers

Vexed, I punched him in his upper arm to force him out of his trance.
**Head still drooped,** he responded by grabbing my wrist before I could withdraw my hand.

I want to express the idea of him not even raising his head while grabbing my wrist.
His head was originally drooped.

Comment: You have what promises to be an absolute phrase. But the subject *head* needs an affiliation: _**His** head stilled drooped, he responded by grabbing my wrist before I could withdraw my hand._

Comment: Without even lifting his head, he grabbed my wrist mid-punch.

Comment: “Head ... he” - the subject can be inferred, so the clause communicates your intent.

Comment: @Lawrence: An absolute phrase has its own subject. Unlike with a participle phrase, nothing can be inferred from the main clause's subject. Without a designation, *head* could mean *my head* or *his head* or *the goat's head*.